# Can you change a typed datasets provider?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, dataset

Using C# I have created a dataset using vs2010. I added tables and table adapters by dragging and dropping from a SQL server data table.

I want to use that created dataset's table but connect to an access database. How can I do that?

What I'm trying to do here is make one app that can connect to a sql database or an access database that use the same data sets with data tables. Is this even possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  How will you choose which database you will use at any given time?

Comment: are the tables in access and sql the same?

Comment: yes, the tables in access and sql are the same. The database will be chosen at startup.

Comment: Just curious why would you want to connect to `Access DB` as well as `Sql DB` if the data is the same as well as up to date in both why not use the better provider in these terms `The Sql Database` please be more specific in your question as to why you need this..

Comment: Seems like a clumsy workaround to bad database design. Maybe you should address the root problem?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Phrancis... My recommendation is sql express user instance instead of access. This would enable seamless switching. Follow the example posted by @Brij Raj Singh from codemonk to implement Application level connection strings and you will be set.

But if you still want to do it:

1. Make sure your databinding is done in code and not visually.
2. Duplicate your dataset, connecting it to Access
3. create a factory to provide your datasets as datasources
4. use the factory to get your datasources when binding
5. Implement choice at app startup, and pass this choice along to factory class so it can provide the correct datasource

Answer (score 0):

yes offcourse, you can change the connection at the runtime to fill your strongly typed dataset, as long as schema is similar.

http://thecodemonk.com/2008/02/18/tableadapter-connection-strings/

I haven't played with it but theoretically seems promising

Answer (score -1):

1. You cannot mix between SQL Server and Access Database because there
   is differences in the query types..
2. You cannot change the provider of dataset at all because if you check back the created classes of dataset you'll see that it's build to work with either OLEDB or SQL

Comment: I think the first statement is not 100% accurate. `SELECT * FROM table;` statement works fine on both DB engines